# technical question about Probability Joint Density Functions....

Tags: probability

Recently, in my studies I have noticed that when trying to find the limits of integration in a joint density function type of problem, we only look at the graph of the first quadrant. So for example, if we want the $P (X < Y)$, then we graph the function $X<Y$ and look at the graph and find the limits of integration, whatever they may be.

My question is this: We should ONLY look at the first quadrant of the graph correct? This would be because probability cannot be less than $0$ or negative so we should look for the limits of integration in the first quadrant since both $x$ and $y$ would be positive?

Is that correct?

Help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks :)

Comment: It is because many of the random variables that one studies do not take on negative values. so the pair $(X,Y)$ often "lives" in the first quadrant. But that will not apply to other distributions, such as the normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bivariate distribution, your probability function would actually be mapped on the z-axis, no?

In general, you need to look at the support of your bivariate distribution. Sometime, that would extend in the other quadrants too (e.g. bivariate Normal). In an applied setting, like in say, economics, most often you study the first quadrant because certain quantities (say, valuations for a bundle of two products) are implicitly positive, and thus your original density function is truncated so that it lives only on the positive axis.